# Optimized computation of pairwise correlations in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, correlation

Given a set of discrete locations (e.g. "sites") that are pairwise related in some categorical ways (e.g. general proximity) and contains local level data (e.g. population size), I wish to **efficiently** compute the mean correlation coefficients between local level data on pairwise locations that are characterized by the same relationships.

For example, I assumed 100 sites and randomized their pairwise relations using values 1 to 25, yielding the triangular matrix `relations`:

```
import numpy as np

sites = 100
categ = 25

relations = np.random.randint(low=1, high=categ+1, size=(sites, sites))
relations = np.triu(relations) # set relation_ij = relation_ji
np.fill_diagonal(relations, 0) # ignore self-relation
```

I also have 5000 replicates of simulation results on each site:

```
sims = 5000
res = np.round(np.random.rand(sites, sims),1)
```

To compute the mean pairwise correlation for each specific relation category, I first calculated for each relation category `i` the correlation coefficient `rho[j]` between the simulation results `res` of each unique site pairs `j`, and then taking the average across all possible pairs with relation `i`:

```
rho_list = np.ones(categ)*99

for i in range(1, categ+1):
    idr = np.transpose(np.where(relations == i)) # pairwise site indices of the same relation category
    comp = np.vstack([res[idr[:,0]].ravel(), res[idr[:,1]].ravel()]) # pairwise comparisons of simulation results from the same relation category
    comp_uniq = np.reshape(comp.T, (len(idr), res.shape[1], -1)) # reshape above into pairwise comparisons of simulation results between unique site pairs

    rho = np.ones(len(idr))*99 # correlation coefficients of all unique site pairs of current relation category

    for j in range(len(idr)): # loop through unique site pairs
        comp_uniq_s = comp_uniq[j][np.all(comp_uniq!=0, axis=2)[j]].T # shorten comparisons by removing pairs with zero-valued result
        rho[j] = np.corrcoef(comp_uniq_s[0], comp_uniq_s[1])[0,1]

    rho_list[i-1] = np.nanmean(rho)
```

Although this script works, but once I increase `sites = 400`, then the entire computation can take more than 6 hrs to finish, which leads me to question my use of array functions. What is the reason for this poor performance? And how can I optimize the algorithm?

Comment: See if these help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143417, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650188

Comment: @Divakar Thanks. I took a few days to study those links, which taught me a lot about vectorizing the process using `einsum`. However, I still don't see how I can apply them to my problem given that I need to compute the correlation coefficients for array pairs after I remove zero-valued results from them (see above script `comp_uniq_s = comp_uniq[j][np.all(comp_uniq!=0, axis=2)[j]].T`).

Comment: `np.corrcoef(comp_uniq_s[0], comp_uniq_s[1])[0,1]` is not the same value as `np.corrcoef(comp_uniq[j][0], comp_uniq[j][1])[0,1]`.  Is that intended?  Your comments makes it seem like removing zero values is just to reduce computations, not change the outcome.

Comment: Biggest time-saver I can find off the top is changing `np.all(comp_uniq!=0, axis=2)[j]` to `np.all(comp_uniq[j].astype(bool), axis=-1)`, so you 1) don't create the big boolean matrix each iteration and 2) save some time on useless comparisons when `([0]).asytpe(bool) = ([False])`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can vectorize the innermost loop with `j` iterator with some `masking` to take care of the ragged nature of data being processed at each iteration of that loop. We can also take out slowish `np.corrcoef` (inspired by [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30143754/3293881)). Additionally, we can optimize few steps at the start of the outer-loop, specially the stacking steps, which could be the bottlenecks.

Thus, the complete code would reduce to something like this -

```
for i in range(1, categ+1):
    r,c = np.where(relations==i)

    A = res[r]
    B = res[c]

    mask0 = ~((A!=0) & (B!=0))
    A[mask0] = 0
    B[mask0] = 0

    count = mask0.shape[-1] - mask0.sum(-1,keepdims=1)
    A_mA = A - A.sum(-1, keepdims=1)/count
    B_mB = B - B.sum(-1, keepdims=1)/count

    A_mA[mask0] = 0
    B_mB[mask0] = 0

    ssA = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',A_mA, A_mA)
    ssB = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',B_mB, B_mB)
    rho = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',A_mA, B_mB)/np.sqrt(ssA*ssB)

    rho_list[i-1] = np.nanmean(rho)
```

**Runtime tests**

Case # 1: On given sample data, with sites = `100`

```
In [381]: %timeit loopy_app()
1 loop, best of 3: 7.45 s per loop

In [382]: %timeit vectorized_app()
1 loop, best of 3: 479 ms per loop
```

**`15x+`** speedup.

Case # 2: With `sites = 200`

```
In [387]: %timeit loopy_app()
1 loop, best of 3: 1min 56s per loop

In [388]: %timeit vectorized_app()
1 loop, best of 3: 1.86 s per loop

In [390]: 116/1.86
Out[390]: 62.36559139784946
```

**`62x+`** speedup.

Case # 3: Finally with `sites = 400`

```
In [392]: %timeit vectorized_app()
1 loop, best of 3: 7.64 s per loop
```

This took `6hrs+` at OP's end with their loopy method.

From the timings, it became clear that vectorizing the inner loop was the key to getting noticeable speedups for large `sites`.

Comment: Please don't bother benchmarking my (deleted now) answer.  It was . . . real bad once I got a chance to check the timings.

Comment: @Divakar I studied your code and honestly still don't fully understand it yet amazed at how well/accurate it works. Ex: the `masking` you used seems to simply replace certain pairs with 0 values, and then computed correlations from these 0-inflated arrays. However, given `a=[1,2,3,0,4,0]` and `b=[0,4,0,3,2,1]`, `np.corrcoef(a,b)[0,1]` != the zero-inflated `np.corrcoef(a0,b0)[0,1]`, where `a0 = [0,2,0,0,4,0]` and `b0 = [0,4,0,0,2,0]`. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: @Divakar I also noticed that in the [older version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650188/efficient-pairwise-correlation-for-two-matrices-of-features) of your script for calculating the Pearson's correlation coefficient, it uses a slightly different 4-parts breakdown of the formula than here and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143417/computing-the-correlation-coefficient-between-two-multi-dimensional-arrays). Do you have a preference on how to numerically deconstruct the calculation?